# I want to show users their location on my web site in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ip-address

On page load users the page shall display the location of the user using ip address, I have this javascript this fetches me the location but instead of  alert i want it to display in a label control or something

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="http://api.easyjquery.com/easyjquery.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

    // 1. Your Data Here
    function my_callback(json) {
        alert("IP :" + json.IP + " COUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY);
    }

    function my_callback2(json) {
       alert("IP :" + json.IP + " COUNTRY: " + json.COUNTRY + " City: " + json.cityName + " Region Name: " + json.regionName);
    }

    // 2. Setup Callback Function
    // EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback");      // fastest version
    EasyjQuery_Get_IP("my_callback2","full"); // full version

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a additional div into the body tag of your website:

```
[...]
</head>
<body>
[...]
<div id="location">Loading location...</div>
```

Update your JavaScript, instead of the lines starting with `alert()` use:

```
document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = "IP: " + json.IP + " Country: " + json.COUNTRY + " City: " + json.cityName + " Region Name: " + json.regionName;
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/gJKue/6/

Comment: My fault, it's `innerHTML` not innerHtml! It should work now, added also a link to an example.

Comment: If it does not work on your page, you have to add $(document).ready() around the EasyjQuery_Get_IP call.